# How to bookmark the contents of a Word table cell without carrying over the cell formatting (Word VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to bookmark the contents of a Word table cell (the contents will be numbers) so that I can cross-reference the bookmark in text elsewhere in the document - the goal being that if the numbers in the cells change, by running an "update all fields" macro (which I already have) I can update all of the in-text references to these numbers without having to manually scour the entire document. I've been through the interwebs and found something similar (my adapted version is shown below), however the issue with this method is that when I try to cross-reference the bookmark, it keeps the cell formatting - so there will be text and then suddenly a random cell and then more text. The good thing about this method is that the number does actually update as it's supposed to, I just can't get rid of the cell formatting.

```
Sub BookmarkCurrentCell()

    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        selectedTable = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Tables(1).Range.End).Tables.Count
        selectedColumn = Selection.Information(wdStartOfRangeColumnNumber)
        selectedRow = Selection.Information(wdStartOfRangeRowNumber)
    End If
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="Bookmark_" & selectedTable & "_" & selectedRow & "_" & selectedColumn, Range:=ActiveDocument.Tables(selectedTable).Cell(selectedRow, selectedColumn).Range

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub BookmarkCurrentCell()
Dim rng As Range
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        selectedTable = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Tables(1).Range.End).Tables.Count
        selectedColumn = Selection.Information(wdStartOfRangeColumnNumber)
        selectedRow = Selection.Information(wdStartOfRangeRowNumber)
    End If
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Tables(selectedTable).Cell(selectedRow, selectedColumn).Range
    rng.End = rng.End - 1
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="Bookmark_" & selectedTable & "_" & selectedRow & "_" & selectedColumn, Range:=rng

End Sub
```

I think the problem is that you are applying the bookmark to the entire cell, the modified code sets a range = to the cell range, then moves the end of the range back 1 character so that it only includes the cell contents (and not the actual cell).